# Is it possible to export "Saved Queries" and "Scheduled Queries" in Bigquery to Terraform code?

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

We have Saved Queries on project visibility, as well as scheduled queries on our Bigquery project.

I would like to transport these through terraform if its possible. The current documentation doesnt seem to mention saved queries but only Bigquery jobs or routines.

Thank you for help,

Checked documentation on both sides.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970